# no module named mysite.wsgi django Heroku Deployment

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku, django-deployment

i am trying to deploy my django project on heroku backed by postgreSQL
it runs fine on local however while deploying deployment is successful
when i run the url like myapp.herokuapp.com, it throughs error

my Procfile code:

`web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi --log-file -`

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
import sys


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")


application = get_wsgi_application()
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from pathlib import Path
import dj_database_url
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-!j&awpwhyus30$je(5de%5w5b%e-nu_alq!2g)rwfn3-wia94='

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1','dmhc.herokuapp.com']
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'admin_interface',
    'colorfield',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mysite',
    'tinymce',
    'captcha',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {            
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'mysite.context_processor.course_renderer',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    # 'default': {
    #     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    #     'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    # }
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'DMHC',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '123',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#location where django collect all static files
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
# location where you will store your static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'mysite/static')]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {

   'height': 360,

   'width': 1000,

   'cleanup_on_startup': True,

   'custom_undo_redo_levels': 20,

   'selector': 'textarea',

   'theme': 'modern',

   'plugins': '''

   textcolor save link image media preview codesample contextmenu

   table code lists fullscreen insertdatetime nonbreaking

   contextmenu directionality searchreplace wordcount visualblocks

   visualchars code fullscreen autolink lists charmap print hr

   anchor pagebreak

   ''',


   'toolbar1': '''

   fullscreen preview bold italic underline | fontselect,

   fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor | alignleft alignright |

   aligncenter alignjustify | indent outdent | bullist numlist table |

   | link image media | codesample |

  

   ''',

   'toolbar2': '''

   visualblocks visualchars |

   charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor | code |

   ''',

   'contextmenu': 'formats | link image',

   'menubar': True,

   'statusbar': True,

   }
```

**Project Structure :**

[image: my project structure looks like this image]

**log trail looks like this:**

[image: heroku log trail]

your assistance is much appriciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is your `Procfile` on the same level as your `manage.py` file?

Comment: no, it is not.. manage.py is inside DHMC/mysite and Procfile is in DHMC/ directory

Comment: They should be on the same level

Comment: no luck still getting same error after deployment

Comment: Can you show your requirements file?

Comment: ```
asgiref==3.3.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2.3
django-admin-interface==0.16.3
django-colorfield==0.4.1
django-flat-responsive==2.0
django-flat-theme==1.1.4
django-ranged-response==0.2.0
django-simple-captcha==0.5.14
django-tinymce4-lite==1.8.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
jsmin==2.2.2
Pillow==8.2.0
psycopg2==2.8.6
pytz==2021.1
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
whitenoise==5.2.0

```